# Is there a way to mock `module` variable?

Tags: node.js, webpack, mocha.js, sinon, jestjs

I want to test my app `init` function, that depends on node.js `module` variable (`webpack`'s `module` variable to be precise). I can't pass `module` variable as a function parameter because of this [`webpack` GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5668).

I found this [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) library, that seems to be good for my problem. But it looks like it is abandoned and has some errors because of my ES6 imports.

Code sample I want to test:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React from 'react'

import Root from './components/Root'

export function init() {
  const {AppContainer} = require('react-hot-loader')
  const render = Component => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <Component />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
  }

  render(Root)

  if (module.hot) { // the part I would like to test by mocking `module` variable
    module.hot.accept('./components/Root', () => { render(Root) })
  }
}

init()
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @alexmac updated my question

Comment: Not sure that you _can_ and _should_  create a stub for module. You can try the following: create a new function `export.getHot = () => module.hot;`, use it in your module and create a stub for it in a test.

Comment: @alexmac I think this is a good idea, thank you